# Blender doesn't work on a server

Tags: command-line

I have a server with Linux installed on it. I also installed Blender with `apt install blender` and I want to start a render on it with `blender -b <file.blend> -a` but it returns those errors :
[image: Error returned in command prompt]

Do you know how to fix that ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. Those errors are related to the sound card and my server doesn't ahve one. So the solution is to disable sound with :

```
blender -noaudio -b
```